# DIY USB-C charging port won't work with lightning cable

Tags: low-power, charger, usb-c, lightning

I have this project where I wan't to add a USB-C port to my e-bike.

There is a front light powered by the battery, which I removed. I checked it, and it outputs 6V.

[image]

I then took a USB-A to USB-C cable, and connected it to the + and - from the bike. I checked with my multimeter, and it looks like it's connected to the correct pins (A4, A9, B4 and B9 if I remember correctly) and ground on the USB-C connector.

[image]

Then I connected a USB-C to lightning cable (official from Apple, which I've tested works on other equipment), and tested it with my AirPods and my iPhone; but to my suprise, no response.

[image]

[image]

But When I connected a USB-C wireless QI charger, it worked fine.

[image]

What's going on here? Why doesn't the lightning cable work here?

Comment: Did you connect the polarity detection resistors to the cable?

Comment: USB-C has some stuff to negotiate how much power the device is allowed to use. I bet the phone is smartly trying to talk to the bike to know how much power it can use, but the wireless charger isn't

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica No. I only have access to + and - wires from the bike battery.

Comment: @user253751 That sounds plausible, yes.

Comment: Is there any way to get it to work?

Comment: 6V is 21% more than 5V. You might damage devices that don't expect to see 5V that is so much out of tolerance. And the devices are unable to communicate how much they are allowed to draw current so they may not charge at all.

Comment: Try shorting the D wires together. That is the most basic negotiation configuration.